# How to enable last 3 months date from current date in DHTML v1.0

Tags: javascript, calendar, dhtml

```
if(date.getFullYear() == now.getFullYear())
      {
        if(date.getMonth() < now.getMonth() - 3)
          {
            return true;  // disable other dates
          }
        if(date.getMonth() == now.getMonth() - 3)
          {
            if(date.getDate() < now.getDate())
            {
              return true;
            }
          }   
      }
```

This code is working fine.But what if the current date is in February. It is not disabling the December since it is included in 3 months. Please share your opinion on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var threeMonthsAgo = new Date();
threeMonthsAgo.setMonth(threeMonthsAgo.getMonth() - 3);
return threeMonthsAgo <= date
```

Comment: @VimalKumar Feel free to accept the answer if you think it's helpful. Thanks.